# Fix TIMESSTAMP data in Netbeans Java Table

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, timestamp

my java code store date and time in mysql table using TIMESSTAMP. This is my code for it:

```
java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();
java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

//sql

```
String sqlstock = "insert into stock values ('"+barcode+"','"+item_name+"','"+quantity+"','"+sdf.format(dt)+"')";
```

My table show data like this: 2015-12-15 16:18:31
That is the correct format. I like that.

On the other hand i need to load it for Table. My table load that data as STRING.

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
       Object[] row = {resultSet.getString(1),resultSet.getString(2),resultSet.getDouble(3),resultSet.getString(4)};
       dtmxx.addRow(row);

}
```

resultSet.getString(4) is that date and time. The problem is here. In that date and time showing like this at TABLE: 2015-12-15 16:18:31.0

You can see ".0" is not in my database table. But in this JAVA TABLE it automatically showing.

MQSQL DATABASE TABLE DATA SHOWING LIKE THIS : 2015-12-15 16:18:31
JAVA TABLE DATA SHOWING LIKE THIS : 2015-12-15 16:18:31.0

I want to remove that **.0** from my JAVA TABLE RESULT.

HOPE you can understand what i want and clear my situation. 
Thank you for your time.[image]

Comment: Very first thing to do: stop building your SQL like that. Use parameterized SQL instead. Next, understand that if the field in your database is a timestamp, the format of it isn't going to be text anyway (I'd hope). You're just seeing a text *representation*. You should use `resultSet.getTimestamp()` and format that.

Comment: Thank you  – Jon Skeet . Yes used "resultSet.getTimestamp()" But same result.

Comment: BUT USED THIS WAY. AFTER THE "ss" I ADDED ".0" NOW SAME RESULT. BUT I CAN USE THAT DATE AND TIME AS PRIMARY KEY. PLEASE TELL ME ANYONE THIS METHOD IS CORRECT OR NOT?        java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();
       java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.0");