# This TIMESSTAMP method correct or not in java?

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, timestamp

my java code store date and time in mysql table using TIMESSTAMP. This is my code for it:

```
java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();
   java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.0");
```

I want to know that **"ss.0"** in the SimpleDateFormat is correct way or not? Is this will be a problem? First i got [another problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34722487/fix-timesstamp-data-in-netbeans-java-table)  You can see it following my link. After that i found this method to fix it. So finally i need to know my way is correct or not?

Can i add .0 with it?

Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't use a string to pass a timestamp to your SQL statement. You should use a PreparedStatement, and pass a java.sql.Timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

It is legal and will print .0 after the seconds part.
Not sure what you're trying to do though, maybe you can explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: thank you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34722487/fix-timesstamp-data-in-netbeans-java-table please follow it. That is my main problem. After that found that solution. First i tried to do it without .0 but finally i found this way and i changed my code to use .0 So i want to know this way is correct or not?

Comment: As one of the commenters on your original post said, use getTimestamp(). What I didn't understand is what do you want to see in your response?

Comment: I am beginner to java. So i cannot  clear more ways. But i am learning with your comments. Yes now i used getTimestamp(). But the result is same. It is getting with.0 after the ss. So That time is my one of PRIMARY key. When it showing in the JAVA TABLE it is with .0 So that JAVA TABLE out put and SQL TABLE data are not same. If i used this way  java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.0"); i can fix it. SO i want to know this way having any problem? Can i used this way? Now my problem is fixed with my own way. But want to know is this correct?